# Are Li's numbers strictly increasing?

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, differential-calculus

Li's numbers $\lambda_{n}$ are defined by:

$\lambda_{n} = \sum_{\rho} \Big(1-\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^n + 1-\Big(1-1/{\overline{\rho}}\Big)^{n}\Big)$

Where $n$ is real and $\rho$ runs over all the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function and  is always paired together with $1-\rho$.

We claim that the derivative of $\lambda$ with respect to $n$ exists everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.

Indeed, begin with

$\frac{d}{dn} \lambda_{n} = -\sum_{\rho} \Big(\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^n\log\Big(1-1/\rho\Big) + \Big(1-1/{\overline{\rho}}\Big)^n\log\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)\Big) $

Then note that for any fixed real $n$, as Im$\rho \to \infty$, the summand tends to $-\Big(1/\rho + 1/\overline{\rho}\Big)$, and convergence occurs due to the pairing of the zeros.

We therefore conclude that $\lambda$ is differentiable (hence continuous) everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, let $h(n) = \lambda_{n} + \lambda_{-n}=2\lambda_{n}$.

$h(n)=:$

$\sum_{\rho}  \Big(1-\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^{n} +  1-\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)^{n} +  1-\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^{-n} +  1-\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)^{-n}\Big) + \sum_{1-\rho}  \Bigg(1-\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}\Bigg)^{n} + 1-\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\overline{\rho}}\Bigg)^{n}  +  1-\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-{\rho}}\Bigg)^{-n} +  1-\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{1-\overline{\rho}}\Bigg)^{-n}\Bigg) $

Observe that in the above, the sum over $\rho$ is exactly equal to the sum over $(1-\rho)$, so that for the purposes of this argument, it suffices to consider only the sum over $\rho$ forthwith.

Suppose that $h$ has a stationary point at some positive real $m$, so that $h'(m)=0$:

$h^{'}(m)=:$
                                                                                                         $\sum_{\rho}\Bigg(-\Bigg( \log\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^{\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^{m}}  +  \log\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)^{\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)^{m}} \Bigg) +                                                                                                   \Bigg( \log\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^{\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^{-m}}  +  \log\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)^{\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)^{-m}} \Bigg)\Bigg)$

Which simplifies to

$h^{'}(m)=\log\prod_{\rho} \beta_{\rho}$

Where
                                                                           $\beta_{\rho} = \Big(1-1/\rho \Big)^{\Big(1-1/\rho \Big)^{-m} -\Big(1-1/\rho \Big)^{m}}\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho} \Big)^{\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho} \Big)^{-m} -\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho }\Big)^{m}}$

Therefore, if $h^{'}(m)=0$, we should have
                                                                                                       $\prod_{\rho} \beta_{\rho}=1$

But one can quickly verify that this is impossible for any nonzero real $m$, and a contradiction is reached.

Hence it follows that $h$ has no stationary points for $n>0$, and by its continuity, this implies that $\lambda_{n}$ is either a strictly increasing or strictly decreasing function of $n$ for $n> 0$. But we already know from computational evidence  that $0<\lambda_{1} < \lambda_{2} < \lambda_{3}<\cdots<\lambda_{3 000} $, therefore the only remaining possibility is that    $\lambda_{n}$ is strictly increasing with positive $n$ ?

Comment: You may also see https://www.academia.edu/s/70a118b938/on-the-nonnegativity-of-lis-numbers-and-the-riemann-hypothesespdf?source=link

Comment: I'm not sure if the downvote was necessary.

Comment: you guess this is the first thing Li tried, and since he didn't success, it means you made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @user1952009, there is absolutely no reason to believe that assertion.

Comment: what does it change when there is an exceptional $\rho = 1/2+\epsilon+i\gamma$

Comment: @user1952009, i'm not sure what you mean by ''it''.The best thing you could do is to point out a specific flaw in the argument.

Comment: I just did : what does it change in your argument when there is a $\rho, Re(\rho) \ne 1/2$

Comment: The same question can be asked for the Li criterion itself: What does it change to $\lambda_n$ if there is a zero off the critical line ? The answer to that question is the same answer to your question.

Comment: do you know how to prove Li's criterion ? then try with $\lambda_n$ the Taylor coefficients of $\frac{\phi'}{\phi}(z)$ with $\phi(z) = f(\frac{1}{1-z}), f(s) = \xi(s)(s-a)(s-\bar{a})(s-1+a)(s-1+\bar{a}), Re(a) \ne 1/2$, you'll see your (non) argument fails.

Comment: How does it fail ? Isn't it amazing that you're the only one talking about that ?

Comment: do you understand that $\prod_\rho \beta_\rho = 1$ is directly equivalent to  $Re(\rho) \le 1/2$ ? so you need to use another property of $\zeta(s)$ for showing it.

Comment: Why can't you just do the simple: Point out an error in the above argument by making reference to a specific line. You *might* see why everyone is quiet modulo you.

Comment: it is a typo, I meant $Re(\rho) > 1/2$ (or $|\rho-1| < |\rho|$). if you read joro's linked article, you will see it.

Comment: blablabla, prove the Li's criterion, and you'll see that proving $\prod_\rho \beta_\rho  \ne 1$ only from : "the series for $\lambda_n$ converges" and "$\rho$ comes with $1-\rho$ and $\bar{\rho}$" is a non-sense.

Comment: Actually, what's ''non-sense'' is what you have just said. And by the way, your ''typo'' above where you inserted ''$\leq$'' instead of $''>''$, is TEXnichally *stunning*.

Comment: you didn't provide any argument for $\prod_\rho \beta_\rho \ne 1$, and I showed there is none if you assume only : "$\lambda_n$ converges" and "the symmetry of the $\rho$ under $s \mapsto 1-s$ and $s \mapsto \bar{s}$" (see my $\phi(z)$ counter-example above)

Comment: Simple, if $\prod_{\rho}\beta_{\rho} \neq 1$, then the derivative would be nonzero. And your statement beginning with ''i showed...'' is not justified to say the very least, while your ''counter-example'' is not even addressing any line of the argument whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

I think positivity of $\lambda_n$ is Li criterion, which is equivalent 
to Riemann hypothesis.

See [A Li-type criterion for zero-free half-planes of Riemann's zeta function](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507368)

Comment: Yes they are equivalent, but does this answer the *asked* question ?

Comment: tks for the linked article

Answer (score 2):

Li's criterion is very well explained in joro's linked article.

It applies to any entire function $\prod_\rho (1-\frac{z}{\rho})(1-\frac{z}{\overline{\rho}}), \rho \ne 1$ as a criterion that $Re(\rho) \le 1/2$ (*),

and so does your "non vanishing of $\frac{d}{dn}\lambda_n$" idea.

Hence, for proving the RH you have to replace *"one can quickly verify that this is impossible for any nonzero real $m$"* by a deep argument making $\xi(s)$ special, and that doesn't apply to, say, $\xi(s)(s-a)(s-\bar{a}), Re(a) > 1/2$.

Take a look at the [Selberg class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class), you'll see all the properties of $\zeta(s)$  you need to use in order to hope proving the RH (once you remove any of those properties, you get many functions very close to $\zeta(s)$ but for which the RH fails).

---

(*) **Li's criterion is indeed very simple** : $|1-\frac{1}{\rho}| < 1 \Leftrightarrow |\rho-1| < |\rho| \Leftrightarrow Re(\rho) > 1/2$.
Then, starting with an entire function $f(s) = \prod_\rho (1-\frac{s}{\rho})$, let $\phi(z) = f(\frac{1}{1-z})$.

Its zeros are at $\frac{1}{1-z} = \rho \Leftrightarrow z = 1-\frac{1}{\rho}$. Hence, $\frac{\phi'(z)}{\phi(z)}$ is holomorphic on the unit disk $|z| < 1$ if and only if $|1-\frac{1}{\rho}| \ge 1$ i.e. iff $Re(\rho) \le 1/2$.

Write the Taylor series $\frac{\phi'(z)}{\phi(z)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n $ and since $\log \phi(z) = \sum_\rho \log (1-\frac{1}{\rho (1-z)}) = \sum_\rho \log(1-\frac{1}{\rho}-z)-\log(1-z)$ we have $$\frac{\phi'}{\phi}(z) = \sum_\rho \frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\rho}-z}$$ so that $c_n = \sum_\rho 1-(1-\frac{1}{\rho})^{-n-1} = \sum_\rho 1-(1-\frac{1}{1-\rho})^{n+1}$.

The condition $Re(\rho) \le 1/2$ then becomes equivalent to $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |c_n|^{1/n} \ge 1$.
Finally, if $\rho$ comes with its complex conjugate $\bar{\rho}$, then $c_n = \sum_{\rho} Re(1-\Big(1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}\Big)^{n+1})$ that is obviously $\ge 0$ for any $n \ge 0$ whenever $|1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}| \le 1 \Leftrightarrow|1-\frac{1}{\rho}| \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow Re(\rho) \le 1/2$ . Conversely, ordering the $\rho$ by $|1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}|$, you see that the largest $|1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}|> 1$ term dominates the sum  as $n \to \infty$, and hence $c_n$ becomes negative sometimes .

Comment: @user1952009, let me ask you a simple question, which requires a straightforward answer: What is the derivative of $\lambda$ with respect to $n$ ?

Comment: @TatendaIsaaacKubalalika I said your series for $d\lambda_n / dn$ is valid in the case of $\rho$ the zeros of $\xi(s)$, and in general whenever $\sum_\rho \frac{1+\left|\operatorname{Re}(\rho)\right|}{(1+|\rho|)^2}$ converges (and $\rho \ne 1$)

Comment: @user1952009, I asked a very simple question:what is the derivative of $\lambda$ wrt $n$ ? I want to hear it from you.

Comment: @TatendaIsaaacKubalalika It's $-\sum_{\rho} \Big(\Big(1-1/\rho\Big)^n\log\Big(1-1/\rho\Big) + \Big(1-1/{\overline{\rho}}\Big)^n\log\Big(1-1/\overline{\rho}\Big)\Big) $

Comment: @TatendaIsaaacKubalalika ok, I proved it vanishes (sometimes, and infinitely often) whenever one of the $\rho$ has real part $> 1/2$ (and greater than all the others. when many $\rho$ have same real part $> 1/2$, you need to use the argument that $f(n) = \sum_m \cos( w_m n), n \in \mathbb{R}$ changes of sign infinitely often whenever all the $w_m > 0$)

Comment: @TatendaIsaaacKubalalika now I suggest you writing a detailed proof of "$d\lambda_n/d_n$ doesn't vanish", you'll probably find the flaw, or you can post it to me and I will.

Comment: the problem is that you didn't understand the derivation of Li's criterion, in particular think about this sentence : $$ $$ "you see that the largest $|1-\frac{1}{1-\rho}|> 1$ term dominates the sum  as $n \to \infty$, and hence $c_n$ becomes negative sometimes "

Comment: I guess i might have to reach for my dictionary and search the word ''understand''. And hold on, the $c_n$ in this case are Li's numbers ?

Comment: And let me say again that, assuming the RH, computational evidence *strongly* suggests that $\lambda_n$ is strictly increasing with positive $n$ so that the derivative never vanishes.